# How do you copy and paste into Git Bash

Tags: git, windows-xp, copy-paste, msysgit

I'm using [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) running on Windows XP.

Tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, Right click, Middle click, google... no luck.

Comment: @hobbs has the answer you are looking for! Right-click the top left corner of the window (the icon) select PROPERTIES and select "QUICK EDIT MODE"

Comment: I've seen is added but here's a link https://www.udacity.com/wiki/ud775/git-bash-copy-paste

Comment: Another usefull page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267062/after-pasting-a-yanked-line-in-vim-why-cant-i-paste-it-again

Answer (score 1070, accepted):

Press <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Also, to copy *from* the window, try clicking the console's window icon (topleft) and choosing Edit -> Mark, then drag a box on the text, then press Enter. (You can also paste via the window icon menu, but the key is faster.)

**UPDATE**

Starting from Windows 10 the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and a lot of other feature are implemented in conhost.exe so they should work with every console utility on Windows. (You have to enable Properties -> Option tab -> Quick Edit Mode)

Ref: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/

Comment: What I want is to paste content `into` git bash. But thanks to you, I spotted `Edit -> Paste` which is exactly what I want! No more typing API code manually!

Comment: Glad my answer helped, even if slightly circuitously. ;)

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not msysgit's fault, but rather an issue because msys uses `cmd.exe`.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but the fancy "Insert" key formatting initially made me miss the "Press Insert." part.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is also true in msysgit, but in git bash, using Edit->Mark->Enter copies line breaks or something. I was trying to create a new ssh key for bitbucket and using your suggestion gave me an "Invalid Key" message. So instead, I did cat ~/.ssh/mykeyfile > /c/Users/user/pub.txt and copied it from Notepad instead. Not saying your answer is wrong (actually it's perfectly correct and I upvoted it), but in case people run into copy/paste issues, I thought I'd mention this.

Comment: @tandrewnichols yes, Mark->Enter in the Windows terminal copies what's literally in the terminal, rather than being aware of lines. (Basically it comes down to Windows terminals being pretty dumb, sadly.)

Comment: Fuuuuuu, I am on mac running windows, I don't have INSERT

Comment: @KevinT you can use the "click on the console window icon" method then, it'll just be a little slower.

Comment: I too do not have an insert key! Why do they remove the ability to paste in bash?!?

Comment: @BillyNair You can still paste into Git Bash even without an Insert key - just use the menu method.

Comment: Thanks, btw on Win 7 I have to use `Shift + Ins`, otherwise it says something like `[(^2A](` and so forth.

Comment: for folk using Parallels Desktop: add the shortcut of your liking in Preferences > Shortcuts > [your virtual machine]: I've set cmd+alt+i = insert

Comment: Shift-Insert required on Lubuntu as well.

Comment: @kevin and Mac users.  Number Pad 0 is Insert on Windows.

Comment: For those of you like me that have a Lenovo laptop without an Insert key, `Fn + i` will paste into the Git shell.

Comment: @Poma thanks, for me using Shift+FN+Enter allows me to paste into git bash while running in parallels.

Comment: Starting from Windows 10 the Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V is implemented in conhost so it should work with every console utility on Windows. (You have to enable Properties -> Option tab -> Quick Edit Mode)

Comment: Anyone else dumb enough to look for an `Insert` option in the menu? I've never seen the keyboard markup before, and I don't think I've ever used to the Insert key as a Windows user on *purpose*. If not, I will gladly be your Village Idiot for the day, with scheduling flexibility.

Comment: This also applies to mintty, although the remark about `conhost` obviously does not.  Ctrl-V doesn't work in mintty and Shift-Insert is standard.

Comment: I am running Git Bash in Windows 10 using a Mac Keyboard... I have tried every keyboard shortcut suggestion on this list without success.

Comment: on Win 7 I used Win + Insert

Comment: how come in 2021 apps still exist in which default key bindings are absent?

Comment: @Amber I downwoted you, because it does not work by only pressing Intert key. i had to press shift + Insert then it worked on win 10 pro!!

Comment: Those instructions for changing the default didn't work for me. Instead I had to go into the Git Bash options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142162/can-git-bash-shell-using-the-default-windows-shortcuts-for-copy-paste/61302661#61302661

Answer (score 146):

Aside from using the edit menu commands, you can directly paste into the git bash window using the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Comment: No need for the Control key, just the Insert key works to paste

Comment: how to cancel the paste? is there any shortcuts? Thanks!

Comment: @Dan Rigby I am using latest msysgit at it doesn't work pasting. Triedied with bouth Menu->Paste and also hitting INSERT

Comment: @Ghita it sounds like the content you want to paste isn't actually on the clipboard (or it's in a format that the shell doesn't understand). I verified locally with the latest version of msysgit that this is still functioning.

Comment: @AntiGameZ undo can be done with `Ctrl-_`. I believe this is all from readline utility, which emulates Emacs, the One True Editor.

Comment: This is toggling between insert and replace for me unfortunately in Ubuntu terminal. In order to paste I had to use Edit -> paste.

Comment: Still not good usability - if I use my INSERT key to paste in the bash window, my keyboard is then on REPLACE, rather than INSERT, which requires that I press INSERT again.

Answer (score 68):

It's not really a function of git, msys, or bash; every windows console program is stuck using the same cumbersome copy/paste mechanism for historical reasons. Turning on [QuickEdit mode](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282301) can help -- or you can install a nice alternative console like [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/), and change your git bash shortcut to use it instead.

Comment: For those who want to know how to use Console2: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/04/05/integrating-the-git-bash-into-console/

Comment: +1 for hysterical raisins. I think I will start using that from now on.

Comment: With QuickEdit on this becomes pretty easy: select, Enter, Insert

Comment: @CharlesB - because QuickEdit is broken, throws weird error messages, and only works sporadically.

Comment: Also with quick edit mode one can paste with a click on the right mouse button. Handy!

Comment: Adding to what Imerus said, you dont even need to press enter for copy...select and double right click. It pastes..

Answer (score 60):

**Copy:**

Long-term solution: Click on Topleft icon > Defaults > Select "QuickEdit Mode" under "Edit Options" > Okay

Then select the text you want to copy. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Short-term solution: Click on Topleft icon > Edit > Mark. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Paste:**

Press <kbd>Insert</kbd>

(If the "QuickEdit Mode" is on, Right clicking might work too.)

Comment: This fixed it for me on Windows 7, after enabling QuickEdit Mode, I can use right click to paste :)

Comment: +1 for the right-click as this works when using a windows VM with a mac keyboard

Answer (score 44):

I'm back to Windows for the first time in a long time and this got me cursing like a docker. I finally found this:

[image: ctrl_shift_letter_shortcuts]

Enabling <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>letter</kbd> shortcuts got me to a Linux-like behaviour that has lowered my blood pressure. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>now works.

Comment: I wish this would have worked for me, but it didn't. I can currently copy paste, but only using shift + insert and not  the ctrl c/v or ctrl shift + c/v . tried other answers too :(

Answer (score 40):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> like in linux bash

Edit: It works even in putty.

Comment: using `mintty 3.4.6`, quite late for this question but no need for `Ctrl`, `Insert` can do the job.

Answer (score 21):

The way I do this is to hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> then press <kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>E</kbd> and finally <kbd>P</kbd>.

On Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> jumps to the window menu, <kbd>Space</kbd> opens it, <kbd>E</kbd> selects *Edit* and <kbd>P</kbd> executes the *Paste* command.

*Get these correct in succession and you can paste a snippet in under 2 seconds.*

Comment: This is mac friendly too (works for those of us using Windows on a mac!)

Comment: Only works for English Windows. On a French OS it would be Alt + Space then M (_Modifier_) and finally O (_Coller_).

Answer (score 11):

This is suggested by the [github help page](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows):

```
clip < filename
```

this copies the contents of filename to the clipboard and is useful for doing things like copying your id_rsa.pub to a web form.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Needed to pipe from a git command into my clipboard git diff abc^1 abc -- file | clip

Answer (score 10):

[image]

In windows after this setting you can use ctrl + shift + v ( for windows)

Answer (score 9):

For paste in `Git BASH` <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that worked well and its better than use <Insert

Comment: This is the only keyboard method that worked for me on Win10. Insert (in various combinations) didn't. Quick Edit is enabled.

Answer (score 7):

Right click on the Git Bash shortcut and switch to the **Options** tab. Enable **Quick Edit Mode** and click **OK**.

Now you can use **right click** to paste into Git Bash, even passwords for remote push, which you can't do with **Insert**.

[image]

This also enables copy easily. Just **left click** and **drag** in the console window to select any block of text. Now **right click** on the selection and the text block will be copied in RAM. This is way more easier and intuitive than the other ways.

Image source: https://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/git-for-windows-tip-how-to-copy-and-paste-into-bash/

Answer (score 6):

**Windows**:

1. *Right click*
2. Choose *Options*
3. Choose *Keys*
4. Enable *Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts*

**[How does it look like?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmTC1.png)**

Comment: Not working for me (MINGW/GitBash on Win10), also how this should work if Ctl+C is already assigned?

Answer (score 5):

console2 ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ ) is my go to terminal front end.

it add great features like copy/paste, resizable windows, and tabs. you can also integrate as many "terminals" as you want into the app. i personally use cmd (the basic windows prompt), mingW/msysGit, and i have shortcuts for diving directly into the python and mysql interpreters.

the "shell" argument i use for git (on a win7 machine) is:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"`

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd> did it for me in Windows.

Answer (score 4):

if your intention is copy/paste comments for git commits, try set the enviromental variable EDITOR as your favorite plain-text editor (notepad, notepad++ ...) and when you will commit, don't give him the -m option and Git will open your favorite editor for copy/paste you comment

Answer (score 4):

Get Console2.  You configure it to do it multiple different ways.  Works with bash or Windows command prompts.

Answer (score 4):

You can also just right-click in the console window. Be sure (as per earlier answers) to enable both 'Edit Options' in the Properties panel (from the System menu).

Answer (score 3):

In the properties of the console you can activate the "Quick Edit Mode" under "Edit Options", that way you can paste inside the console just right clicking. Or you can use 'Insert' as they say.

Answer (score 3):

To copy select the text and click <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd>

To paste place the cursor where you want to print

and click <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>INS</kbd>

For more options, on the top left click on git-bash icon

Comment: Yours is the most useful answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was actually wondering how to do this today...and coincidentally, Phil Haack posted a tip about using posh-git (Git on powershell), which gives you tab auto-complete and a few more cool bits. I'm not going back to Git bash.

check it out

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yep, copy from somewhere else using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and paste using <kbd>INSERT</kbd>. Work for me on Window 8.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1. Right-click on the git bash.
2. Select Options
3. Click on the Mouse option on the left side bar.
4. Select this highlighted option, it will be used as a paste.
5. Don't worry, you can get the options when you do right-click on the top bar of the terminal.

Comment: Right mouse click after this configuration still triggers visual mode in VIM. holding shift key + right mouse click worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In windows I'm not sure about copy but for paste works Ctrl+Insert.
In Linux copy: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, paste: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I use the **mouse**:

1. mark
2. right click -> copy
3. right click -> paste

Answer (score 0):

COPY:Click the title bar, choose mark, then select the content you want to copy.
PASTE: Copy what you want to past, focus on the bash, hit the insert key on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

For users working on `Windows 7`, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd> works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're not on a Mac.
Use <kbd>insert</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a lot of answers already but non of them worked for me. Fyi I have a Lenovo laptop with win10 and what works for me is the following:

---

Paste = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>prt sc</kbd>

---

Copy = <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I also go through the same problem, git bash does not support tradition method to copy and paste in windows but you can simply copy and paste in single command

## <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>INSERT</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you click at the icon on the upper left corner, a drop-down menu will appear, and you can find the option to copy/paste from there.

Answer (score 0):

on my keyboard insert is located on the same key as a Printscreen.
unfortunately, ctrl + ins doesn't work for me , so i descoved the following working combinations for me:

FN + CTRL + PRT SC - for copy

FN + SHIFT + PRT SC  - for insert

Answer (score 0):

If you want to paste press:

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>insert</kbd>

Comment: This is already mentioned in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677991/2745495).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked is for:

- desktop keyboard: [shift] + [insert] keys to paste
- laptop keyboard:  [shift] + [0] keys to paste

NB: For laptops, the 0 Key at the bottom of the number pad on the upper-right corner of your keyboard will function as an Insert Key when Num Lock is turned off. That is why it is labeled with both 0 and Ins on the key itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the link.
Then press SHIFT + INSERT.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677991/2227743

Comment: Did not work for me on Windows11 and HP Notebook

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 11 users- GitBash version 2.39.0.windows.2 (64-bit):

To copy it's: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

To paste it's: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: HP laptops don't have insert key.

Answer (score -1):

MacBook pro doesnt have an ins key. Use <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to paste