# git bash how to enable quick edit mode?

Tags: git, git-bash, mintty

(my OS is win 10) I can't find option to enable QuickEdit mode?
[image]

when I select block with left click, git bash copy(extend from win 10 command line) by execute `Ctrl + C` automatically. So it terminate process as the following picture.
How can I do? 
[image]

PS: Ctrl-C is not my action,but by terminal automatically when I release left mouse clicking for selecting text

Comment: I douby you're using Windows, but some kind of unix emulator. It's very likely that simply highlighting text will copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: what is quick edit mode? you cannot edit command in your terminal or what?

Comment: @ikegami Git Bash is a software package for Windows that includes Git, Bash and a lot of Linux tools ported on Windows. All these run on top of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org).

Comment: @axiac, Thanks for confirming what I said. Cygwin is a unix emulation layer.

Comment: @Kent, QuickEdit mode is a setting for the Windows Console. With QuickEdit mode on, you can select text to copy without first right-clicking and selecting Mark.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the Windows Console; you're using a terminal built for cygwin, a unix emulation environment. The usual default behaviour for unix terminals is to place text in the clipboard as soon as you select it. You don't need to press Ctrl-C or any other key.

(I don't have your terminal, so I can't verify that this will help, but there's a very good chance that this will address your issue.)

Answer (score 0):

You can just select/highlight the text and it will automatically be placed on clipboard. then you can `Past` it using mouse `Right Click` and  `Clicking Past` or pressing `Shift+Insert` from keyboard on `Windows` machines.

Answer (score 0):

QuickEdit Mode was available in [Git 1.x](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases), but your screenshot is from [Git 2.x](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

You can use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`c` for copy as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8lW8.png).

You can also use your mouse as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afwDj.png).

Also, note that starting from Windows 10 the `Ctrl`+`c`, `Ctrl`+`v` can be used for copy/paste as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304372/how-do-you-copy-and-paste-into-git-bash/2304382#2304382).

Comment: Your link about using Windows 10 Ctrl+c says to turn Quick Edit mode on, which doesn't answer the question -- WHERE IS QUICK EDIT MODE IN 2.x?

Comment: There may be a workaround that I haven't tried because I don't have Windows 10. During GIT Installation, you can choose the option "Use Git from the Windows Command Prompt" as shown [here](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/318.jpg). Then, you can enable QuickEdit Mode in cmd.exe as shown [here](https://www.isunshare.com/images/article/windows-8/quick-edit-mode-in-command-prompt-how-to-open-it/choose-quick-edit-mode-and-tap-ok.png). Please, tell me if it worked.