# Can Git Bash Shell using the default windows shortcuts for Copy & Paste?

Tags: git, git-bash

I'd like to be able to use Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V for copy and paste into the Git Bash Shell.  However, the shell has Ctrl-Insert & Shift-Insert as those actions.

I don't see an obvious way to change these shortcut keys.  Am I missing something obvious?

I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 15):

In Git Bash (2.25) there is an option to change the shortcuts from Ctrl|Shift+Insert to Ctrl-Shift+C|V.
It's still not what you are asking for, but it's much closer to it, than the default shortcuts.

`Options=>Keys=>Shortcuts: activate option "Ctrl+Shift+letter shortcuts"`

Comment: This setting is not working in 3.6.3 version on windows 11

Comment: I had a chance to test Git for Windows 2.41.0 (standalone installer, includes minTTY 3.6.4) on a Windows 11 machine (22H2) and `Ctrl+Shift+C|V` worked fine, once the `Ctrl+Shift+letter`shortcuts have been enabled.

Answer (score 7):

`Properties -> Options -> Enable ctrl key shortcuts` works for me.
Otherwise, you can enable the QuickEdit mode from that same Options menu, and you should be able to use Windows commands in there.

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl-C sends an interrupt signal to the current program. It is useful if you, say, accidentally write a script with an infinite loop. This is why many terminals use alternatives.

I suggest learning the alternatives and leaving Ctrl-C for interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on top bar and select properties then click on options then select both edit option(quick edit mode, insert mode).Properties -> Options -> edit option.emphasized text